# MVVM и комнады

Tags: wpf, mvvm

В WPF для описания кастомных команд есть интерфейс `ICommnad`, и наша комнада будет представлять собой следющий класс:

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ...
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            ...
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

И тогда во ViewModel мы можем просто объявить свойство типа MyCommand и в разметке просто сделать привязку:

```
<Buttom Command={Binding Path=MyCommand}/>
```

Но что если этих комманд хотя бы 10? Делать 10 классов команд? При этом, например, `CanExecute` у некоторых можут совпадать (например в нем просто может проверяться есть выдененный элемент или нет).

Но у нас же есть уже реализованные наследники `ICommand` - это `RoutedCommand` и `RoutedUICommand` и мы можем выполнить `CommandBinding`, добавить его в коллекцию `CommandBindings` и профит. Выглядит это следующим образом:

1. Объявляем публичное статическое свойство типа `RoutedUICommand`

   public static RoutedUICommand = new RoutedUICommand(...)
2. Указывам в разметке

   <Buttom Command={x:Static Memeber=...}/>
3. И делаем привязку через `CommandBindings`. Вот тут появляются первые вопросы. Обработчики по идее надо разместить во `ViewModel`, но тогда через `XAML` сделать привязки не получится, а получится только через код класса (в конструкторе). Если же объявлять их во `View`, то привязки можно делать в `XAML`, но тогда мы захломляем этим `View`

А какие способ(ы) используете Вы? И правильно ли я использую комнады?

Comment: Может это поможет: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я обычно делаю привязку не через XAML, а вручную.

```
class MainVM
{
    public IEnumerable<CommandBinding> SupportedBindings { get; private set; }
    public MainVM()
    {
        SupportedBindings = new List<CommandBinding>
        {
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, New, AlwaysCan),
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, Close, CanOnActiveDocument),
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationExtendedCommands.Exit, Exit, AlwaysCan),
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationExtendedCommands.About, About, AlwaysCan)
        }.AsReadOnly();
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        foreach (var binding in mainVM.SupportedBindings)
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), binding);
    }
}
```

Но если у вас возникают такие вопросы, возможно, вам придётся или написать свой велосипед^W MVVM-framework, или воспользоваться существующим. Например, посмотрите на [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) или [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @VladD, просто мне показалось странным, что нет общепринятого способа, вот и решил спросить у тех кто сталкивался. А про Prism читал, что его имеет смысл применять на больших проектах.

Comment: @Donil: Угу, WPF сам по себе не заточен под MVVM. Prism довольно тяжеловесен, хотя охватывает много. Если у вас небольшая программа, попробуйте MVVM Light.

Comment: > WPF сам по себе не заточен под MVVM

А я почему то думал что WPF как раз таки под MVVM и сделан. Получается я ошибался?:-(

Comment: @Donil: Насколько я понимаю, нет. Просто MVVM настолько хорошо ложится на WPF, что стал фактически стандартом. Но всё же немного допиливать приходится.